# OpenAI GPT-3 API error: Why does the Discord bot on NodeJS return a 404 error in connection with the OpenAI API?

Tags: node.js, axios, discord.js, openai-api, gpt-3

I'm creating a bot for Discord that has integrated the OpenAI model, but it generates a `404` error when making requests.

My code is:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const axios = require('axios');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages],
});

const BOT_TOKEN = 'token here';
const OPENAI_TOKEN = 'token here';
const BOT_APPLICATION_ID = 'token here';

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot está online!');
  registerSlashCommand();
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.commandName === 'ajuda-ai') {
    await interaction.reply('Digite sua mensagem para o GPT-3.');

    const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({
      filter: (msg) => msg.author.id === interaction.user.id,
    });

    collector.on('collect', async (msg) => {
      if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === '/cancelar') {
        collector.stop();
        interaction.channel.send('A conversa foi cancelada.');
        return;
      }

      interaction.channel.send('Aguarde, estou consultando o GPT-3...');

      try {
        const response = await axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci-codex/completions', {
          prompt: msg.content,
          max_tokens: 100,
        }, {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${OPENAI_TOKEN}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });

        await interaction.followUp(`Resposta do GPT-3: ${response.data.choices[0].text.trim()}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.followUp('Desculpe, ocorreu um erro ao buscar a resposta.');
      }

      collector.stop();
    });
  }
});

async function registerSlashCommand() {
  try {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('1116260407414374493');
    if (!guild) return console.error('Não foi possível encontrar o servidor.');

    await guild.commands.create({
      name: 'ajuda-ai',
      description: 'Inicia uma conversa com o GPT-3.',
    });
    console.log('Comando slash registrado.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao registrar o comando slash:', error);
  }
}

client.login(BOT_TOKEN);
```

Working with the OpenAI API is new to me. I'm still adapting. It changes all the time. I've tested some things, but without success.

I checked the tokens and everything before asking for help here to make sure I didn't forget anything.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

All [Engines API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2022-06-03-legacy-endpoints) endpoints are deprecated.

[image: Deprecated]

#### Solution

Use the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) endpoint.

Change the URL from this...

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci-codex/completions
```

...to this.

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/completions
```

Also, set the `model` parameter that is required (see the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions)):

```
const response = await axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/completions', {
  model: 'text-davinci-003',
  prompt: msg.content,
  max_tokens: 100,
}
```